# could not translate expression into sql

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

With the below code I get this error

`InvalidOperationException`:

> Could not translate expression
>   `stok_getmiktar_byyapilanislem(urunler.ID,
>   "SATIS")` into SQL and could not treat
>   it as a local expression.

```
var urundb = (from urunler in db.TBLP1URUNs
              orderby urunler.SERIAL
              where (urunler.ID.Contains(FilitreText) || urunler.URUNADI.Contains(FilitreText))
              && ((kategori1.SERIAL == null) || urunler.SERIAL.StartsWith(kategori1.SERIAL))
              select new
              {
                  UrunNo = urunler.ID,
                  UrunAdi = urunler.URUNADI,
                  Marka = urunler.MARKA,
                  SatisFiyati = urunler.SATFIYAT1.GetValueOrDefault(0),//.ToString() + " " + urunler.SATFIYAT1BIRIM,
                  TedarikFiyati = urunler.TEDFIYAT1.GetValueOrDefault(0),//.ToString() + " " + urunler.TEDFIYAT1BIRIM,
                  PiyasaFiyati = urunler.SATFIYAT2.GetValueOrDefault(0),//.ToString() + " " + urunler.SATFIYAT2BIRIM,

                  Hizmet = (urunler.HIZMETYENSURYIL > 0 && urunler.HIZMETYENSURAY > 0 ?
                                    urunler.HIZMETYENSURYIL.ToString() + " Yıl " + urunler.HIZMETYENSURAY.ToString() + " Ay"
                                : (urunler.HIZMETYENSURYIL > 0 && urunler.HIZMETYENSURAY <= 0 ?
                                        urunler.HIZMETYENSURYIL.ToString() + " Yıl"
                                    : (urunler.HIZMETYENSURYIL <= 0 && urunler.HIZMETYENSURAY > 0 ?
                                            urunler.HIZMETYENSURAY.ToString() + " Ay"
                                            : ""))),
                  TedarikEdilenMiktar = DAOUrun.stok_getmiktar_byyapilanislem(urunler.ID, "TEDARIK"),//this one works fine
                  SatilanMiktar = DAOUrun.stok_getmiktar_byyapilanislem(urunler.ID, "SATIS"),//this one works fine                              

                  Stok = urunler.TEDARIKCISTOKMIKTAR.GetValueOrDefault(0) 
                       - DAOUrun.stok_getmiktar_byyapilanislem(urunler.ID, "SATIS")//error occurs with this one

              });
```

below is `stok_getmiktar_byyapilanislem`

```
public static double stok_getmiktar_byyapilanislem(string urun_id, string yapilanislem)
{
    VeriyazDBDataContext db = new VeriyazDBDataContext(); db.Connection.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString;

    double miktar = (from rows in db.TBLP1ISLEMDETAYs
                     where rows.URUN_ID == urun_id && rows.TBLP1ISLEM.YAPILANISLEM == yapilanislem
                     select rows.MIKTAR).Sum().GetValueOrDefault(0);

    return miktar;
}
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who are or who may be confronted with and suffered from this error
check [Custom Method in LINQ to SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635418/custom-method-in-linq-to-sql-query) and [Calling functions in LINQ queries](http://tomasp.net/blog/linq-expand.aspx)

they say we cannot call our own functions/methods in linq, actually we can but when trying to get something from that query it throws the referred exception in my question.What I really wonder is why this one

```
SatilanMiktar = DAOUrun.stok_getmiktar_byyapilanislem(urunler.ID, "SATIS"),
```

works but this one doesn't

```
Stok = urunler.TEDARIKCISTOKMIKTAR.GetValueOrDefault(0) - DAOUrun.stok_getmiktar_byyapilanislem(urunler.ID, "SATIS")
```

I just wrote some other method like this:

```
public static double GetMevcutMiktar(string urunId,double acilisMiktari) 
{
    double mevcutMiktar = 0;
    mevcutMiktar = acilisMiktari - stok_getmiktar_byyapilanislem(urunId, "SATIS")
    return mevcutMiktar;
}
```

And called it instead of

```
urunler.TEDARIKCISTOKMIKTAR.GetValueOrDefault(0) - DAOUrun.stok_getmiktar_byyapilanislem(urunler.ID, "SATIS")
```