# Call a custom method in linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I need to call a custom method in linq query, e.g.:

```
IQueryable<Person> query = _db.Persons.OrderBy(p => Decrypt(p.Name));
```

However, in this case Decrypt gives me an exception.

I also tried with this approach:

```
IQueryable<Person> query = _db.Persons.AsEnumerable()
                                      .OrderBy(p => Decrypt(p.Name))
                                      .AsQueryable<Person>();
```

However in this case it works but as I'm using this query as a source (SelectMethod) for my ListView, paging is not working when using DataPager control.

Comment: What do `Decrypt(p.Name)` returns?

Comment: It accepts string and return decrypted string, as this field is encrypted in db.

Comment: the exception would be helpful, but i think the problem is that your method `Decrypt` cannot be translated into sql.

Comment: What is your paging criteria? Because you could omit the decrypting until after you have sized down your results.

Comment: The problem is that OrderBy is performed by database which doesn't know anything about Decrypt method implemented in C#. There was a similar question about LINQ to SQL (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635418/custom-method-in-linq-to-sql-query).

Comment: Yes, I understand. I have the same problem with other methods, such as Where(...), etc. My data in db is encrypted (by field) and I'm using EF Code First approach, so I need to decrypt fields. I can do this with the second approach, however then paging not work.

Comment: As I see now the problem is that IQueryable must be sorted (with OrderBy) in order for paging to work.

Comment: You may want to enumerate first, then do ordering similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/24208901/3481183

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually figure out why IS the paging not working. 
It's possible to create custom SQL function and let Decrypt work. For that, you need to create SQL function Decrypt that does the work.

This is simple example:

(SQL part)

```
CREATE FUNCTION ReverseCustName(@string varchar(100))
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @custName varchar(100)
    -- Implementation left as exercise for users.
    RETURN @custName
END
```

and LINQ part

```
[Function(Name = "dbo.ReverseCustName", IsComposable = true)]
[return: Parameter(DbType = "VarChar(100)")]
public string ReverseCustName([Parameter(Name = "string",
    DbType = "VarChar(100)")] string @string)
{
    return ((string)(this.ExecuteMethodCall(this,
        ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())),
        @string).ReturnValue));
}
```

See this for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386973(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

if its LINQ to SQL you cant since it tries to render that to real SQL.
try to cast the Persons to another object class of your own and then it will be Linq to Object and there it will work. i had this issue a few times, i played with it a little bit until it worked.

BTW i think one of the linq extensions is looking for an IComparable, so worse case you can just implement one

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a one-liner which "could" work, but please provide the exception as well.

```
var query = _db.Persons.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(p => Decrypt(p.Name));
```

Your problem is probably, but it is hard to know since we are not given the exception, that you are trying to get your database to execute `Decrypt` which is not possible. The added `ToList()` just enumerates, ie fetches the data from database in this case, and then we can order in memory.

You won't get paging to work the way you want since the database cannot execute the query.

Comment: This not work, because I must return `IQueryable<Person>`. I can try `_db.Persons.ToList().OrderBy(p => Decrypt(p.Name)).AsQueryable();` but in this case, also, paging not work.

Comment: Don't use `ToList` for this, use `AsEnumerable`. There's no need to make a list out of the data.

Comment: I tried this already with `AsEnumerable`, it is noted in my first post.

Comment: What is the exception? Are you even getting an exception?

Comment: No, there is no exception. Only, paging with DataPager control is not working. Actually, pager is working but ListView is not showing new page data.

Comment: Basically I need to order IQueryable but by using a custom func, is it possible ?

Comment: Ah, now I get what you are trying to do and what the issue really is, I would solve it by using a viewmodel and get the viewmodel to load the entire dataset (as a List<T> or similar) and then apply the necessary magic there. The only other way to get paging to work the way you want to is by implementing decrypt at a database level.